# Styling the default scrollbar on the right

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have been trying for the last hour to change the way the default scrollbar looks on browser.I am talking about the main scrollbar on the right not ading a new one and styiling it.I am using the jScrollPane plugin but it does not seem to work or I am not doing something right.Here is my code:

```
$("window").jScrollPane();

window
{
    width: 100%;

    overflow: auto;
}
window
{
    height: auto;

}
```

Comment: See jScrollpane is working: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html

Comment: What's `window` a class? There is no CSS selector called `window`. If you're using `window`, try `html` instead.

Comment: You simply can't do it. It used to be possible in IE, bu not for a couple of years now.

Comment: Tested: works on IE6+, Chrome

Comment: dont use javascript for this. I think is a better solution http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ use css and let the browser decide what to do with this, and if the browser is old let the regular scroll appear. Only if the scroll bar is really really the main thing of the design i will recommend use javascript for totally support

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [website](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html) that A.K. has linked, you will see the **necessary** Jquery and CSS for this to work. I have made them easier to understand for you.

```
$(function()
{
    var win = $(window);
    // Full body scroll
    var isResizing = false;
    win.bind(
        'resize',
        function()
        {
            if (!isResizing) {
                isResizing = true;
                var container = $('#full-page-container'); //this should be the most parent
                // div, right beneath the <body> and covering the entire page. Change the ID HERE.
                // Temporarily make the container tiny so it doesn't influence the
                // calculation of the size of the document
                container.css(
                    {
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    }
                );
                // Now make it the size of the window...
                container.css(
                    {
                        'width': win.width(),
                        'height': win.height()
                    }
                );
                isResizing = false;
                container.jScrollPane( //this is where outer scroll changes
                    {
                        'showArrows': true
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    ).trigger('resize');

// Workaround for known Opera issue which breaks demo (see
// http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/known_issues.html#opera-scrollbar )
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

// IE calculates the width incorrectly first time round (it
// doesn't count the space used by the native scrollbar) so
// we re-trigger if necessary.
if ($('#full-page-container').width() != win.width()) {
    win.trigger('resize');
}

/*Internal scrollpanes. (Not needed if you want to change only the outer)
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
*/
});
```

Now CSS:

```
html
{
    overflow: auto;
}
#full-page-container
{
    overflow: auto;
}
/*** Optional INNER scrolls. 
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.horizontal-only
{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}
***/
```

Don't forget to include Jquery, jscrollpane.css, mousewheel.js, jscrollpane.js